# Connect to server via a local network

Tags: sockets, network-programming

When I launch a server in my pc he is listening any ip and a port 105. If a client on another computer wants connect to the server in my computer he is using local ip address like 192.168.1.101.

If a client will use my local ip address (192.168.1.101:105) to send a request, then my server will be able to receive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as there is a network route between the two computers and no firewall getting in the way: yes.